# Set Theory - Ordered pairs and cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding ordered pairs and the cartesian product.

In Halmos' Naive Set Theory he writes:

A X B = { x : x = (a,b) for some a in A and for some b in B}

Why does he write 'for some'?

if A = {1,2} and B = {3,4}
Dosen't A X B = {(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)}?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if $x=(a,b)\in A\times B$ for *all* $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, doesn't it imply that $A=\{ a\}$ and $B= \{ b \}$ ? It means that the cartesian product only has one element.

Comment: Ah yes i understand but why does Halmos write 'for some'?

Comment: The elements of the set $A\times B$ are defined to be pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ is an element of $A$ (ie *some* element of $A$) and $b\in B$ is an element of $B$ (ie *some* element of $B$). So if $x\in A\times B$, we may write $x=(a,b)$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Note that then, your example would be correct if you took $B=\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that $\{1,2\}\times\{3,4\}=\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$.

However, remember that the condition in the set builder notation is for asking whether *one thing at a time* is an element of the set. We ask:

Is $x=(1,4)$ in $A\times B$? Yes it is, because $(1,4)=(a,b)$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, namely $a=1$ and $b=4$.

But $(1,4)$ does not equal $(a,b)$ for *all* $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ -- for example $(1,4)\ne(a,b)$ when $a=1$ and $b=3$.

So requiring of an $x$ that it equals $(a,b)$ for *all* choices of $a$ and $b$ would be too much to ask. No possible $x$ can meet that condition, so your set would end up being empty (unless both $A$ and $B$ are singletons).

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation!

Comment: I really appreciate the simplicity and beauty/elegance of this answer. I commend you, sir! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Cartesian product as stated could be rewritten as:
$$ A\times B = \{x : x = (a, b), a\in A \quad \text{and} \quad b\in B\} $$
"For some" indicates that he's considering generic $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. What pair of elements can be equal to $(a, b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ possible? There is no such pair when your sets consist of more than one element.

I believe there is a minor typo in your example. The sets are $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$ but somehow a $4$ pops up. If you change $B$ to $\{3, 4\}$ which I believe is what it was originally, then it is correct.

EDIT: I see you have corrected the typo. Now it is correct.